# AWS EC2 - EBS Redundancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an AWS Ubuntu EC2 server running with a single EBS volume. Although I take regular snapshots, I am concerned about data redundancy.

In order to make sure no data loss, is it possible to convert my ec2 instance to RAID 1 configuration by using a recent snapshot? If so, I will be glad if you can guide me how to do it?

I have found couple of documents explaning how to configure RAID for fresh EC2 creations but I couldn't find anything about how to achieve it for the existing server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AWS EBS volumes are already stored in multiple copies behind the scenes. So there is no need to add extra redundancy by way of RAID setup on the instance.

> Amazon EBS volumes are designed to be highly available and reliable. At no additional charge to you, Amazon EBS volume data is *replicated across multiple servers in an Availability Zone to prevent the loss of data from the failure of any single component*.
>
> This makes EBS volumes *20 times more reliable than typical commodity disk drives* [...]

(From **[Amazon EBS availability and durability](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/#Amazon_EBS_availability_and_durability)**)

---

On the other hand back in the days of EBS `standard` (magnetic) volumes it used to be recommended to use RAID 0 or RAID 1 to spread the load across multiple EBS volumes in the same filesystem to achieve a higher performance. Because both bandwidth and IOPS were limited *per-volume* by adding more volumes we could achieve better performance.

Nowadays with the default use of `gp2` (SSD) volumes it's less of an issue because 1) the performance overall is much higher, and 2) the bigger the volume the more IOPS it gets allocated so it doesn't really matter if you have a single EBS volume of 100GB with 300 IOPS or 2x 50GB volumes each with 150 IOPS. You can find more information about this topic in [Amazon EBS volume types](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/features/#Amazon_EBS_volume_types) overview.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Totally agree with this. To add to this answer, yes you could make a RAID1 array if you wanted, but I wouldn't do it myself. If you do, just add another volume and use the standard Linux / OS tools to create it. An important related point for availability is that the EBS volume is replicated in a single availability zone, but snapshots are in S3 which is regional. You could also consider backing up important data in AWS S3, or outside AWS, in such a way that corrupted data doesn't overwrite good data - incremental backups or versioned files / objects.